# Full Youtube video control C#

Tags: c#, stream, youtube

For a project that I'm working on, I need to stream some video's from Youtube. I could use a Shockwave Flash object, but then I have no options to start / stop / restart / change mode.

I need at least to be able to start the vid, stop the vid and changing the volume (maybe I can do that in a workaround tough) through code.

Any ideas / examples will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look how it works here:
[YouTube™ Embedded Video Player: Extended API (C#)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42349/YouTube-Embedded-Video-Player-Extended-API-C)

Functions listed below are available:

- Setting the startup options
- Selecting the item from the playlist
- Setting the autoplay mode
- Setting player's dimension (W/H)
- Changing the border options
- Starting the video at predefined time

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't allow me to start / stop the video through code.

Comment: Here is YouTube JS API https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference. Use player.playVideo():Void method to start video